# Lost internet after update to ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, updates, internet

This is the info I have but I don't know where to go from here:

```
richardabuli@richardabuli-XPS-15-9530:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net –A2  
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)  
Subsystem: Dell BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:0019]  
Kernel modules: bcma, wl
07:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5249 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5249] (rev 01)  
richardabuli@richardabuli-XPS-15-9530:~$ lspci | egrep -i 'network|ethernet'  
06:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)  
richardabuli@richardabuli-XPS-15-9530:~$
```

By "lost internet" I mean that when I click on the internet icon (which is now an empty circular sector with no sign of any activity) on the right top of the ubuntu screen I get the following list:
No network devices available (in grey)

VPN connections
Enable networking
Connection information (in grey)
Edit connections

When I click on 'Enable networking" I get the message "Disconnected - you are now offline"
When I click on "Edit connections" I find my old list of Ethernet and Wifi connections with the indications that they have last used a few days ago (just before the upgrading to 16.04 -- by the way I updated first from 14 to 15 and then from 15 to 16, internet worked with 15) When I click in any of the connections a window opens with the information for the connection which to me looks OK.

Comment: By "lost internet" you mean that the connections shows up but it's not working, or you mean that cards are off, or you mean that the connection is slow? And do you intend both ethernet and wireless cards, or just one of them two?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I edited my question to include the answer. I apologize I answered this late but I have an urgent work and I was forced  to switch  back and work in a Microsoft computer. Now that the work pressure has diminished I will check for your answer daily.

Comment: You did not answer is the problem is with the Ethernet AND WiFi, or just one of the two.

Comment: It is with both. Nothing shows up and the LAN connection does not work either. I have diffuculties fromatting cottectly mu comments so I"ll reproduce here the 5 items that I find in the small window after I click in the (empty) icon for internet:       (1)  No network devices available (in grey)  
(2) VPN connections       (3) Enable networking       (4) Connection information (in grey)        (5) Edit connections

Comment: I upgraded to ubuntu 16 via my LAN connection!

Comment: It is with both. Nothing shows up and the LAN connection does not work either (I upgraded to ubuntu 16 via my LAN connection!). I have difficulties formatting correctly my comments so I"ll reproduce here the 5 items that I find in the small window which opens when I click in the (empty now) icon for internet:       (1)  No network devices available (in grey)  
(2) VPN connections       (3) Enable networking       (4) Connection information (in grey)        (5) Edit connections      In my revised question I describe what happens when I click in the 3 non grayed options.

Comment: Ok, so... Since both are not working, you can try to follow the instructions to install the drivers without internet access: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#STA_-_No_Internet_access

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. Here is what I got:  richardabuli@richardabuli-XPS-15-9530:~$ uname -r
4.4.0-31-generic
richardabuli@richardabuli-XPS-15-9530:~$ dpkg --get-selections | grep headers
linux-headers-3.16.0-71    install
linux-headers-3.16.0-71-generic   install
linux-headers-3.16.0-73    install
linux-headers-3.16.0-73-generic   install
linux-headers-4.4.0-31    install
linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic   install
linux-headers-generic    install
richardabuli@richardabuli-XPS-15-9530:~$ ../pool/restricted/b/bcmwl
bash: ../pool/restricted/b/bcmwl: No such file or directory

Comment: However, I did not use any media to upgrade I did it from internet when it worked. So what to do now. I can perhaps use an USB with a version of ubuntu 16 and use that to locate the directoty where the drivers are? I don't have to tell you taht i am a complete neophite with ubuntu...

Comment: Yes, you need the external media. Obviously these drivers are not on your computer (otherwise there would be no need to install them!).

Comment: I was request by the site to continue this discussion as a 'chat' but I don't know how to do that.  This is what I did:   I used my Windows10 partition to download (A) 'ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64' and then I used 'Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.6.6ex' to create a (B) UUI USB.   Now, from my (boot) ubuntu partition (where I have installed 16.04 but it seems without the drivers for ethernet and wifi) I can see the contents of (B) UUI as well as having access to (A). How do I proceed to install the drivers in my current ubuntu 16.04 system?

Comment: I also found that my email in ubuntu 16.04 receives and send email!!!

Answer (score 0):

Reputation too low to make a comment vs. answer, but have you checked if there are duplicate device listings in Network Manager?

If your e-mail works and other services don't possibly you have the same issue that I had, post upgrade to 16.04, with duplicate entries in the GUI of Network Manager.  These duplicates weren't configured per my network's configuration and thus caused issues.

To resolve I deleted all devices, rebooted, then configured the discovered devices correctly for my LAN's proxy needs.

Comment: If you consider you reputation too low, then mine is negative. Could you tell me how exactly do what you suggest? Thank you.

Comment: Click on the two verticle arrows at the top right, representing the Network Manager, and click Edit Connections.  Delete your devices in the Ethernet and/or Wi-Fi lists.  After rebooting a generic device will be re-added to the list.  Reconfigure the device as per your network configuration, ex: proxy or other settings required by your network.  If nothing shows up after reboot, click Add and then select a device from the drop down.  Good luck!

Comment: It didn't work. A new LAN connection came back but there is no drop down list of devices where to choose from (I don't see any internet signal around, I used to see not only mine but also from neighbors)

Comment: Is it possible that you have turned off the LAN device in your BIOS settings?